# How long does closed testing review take for Android app using Accessibility Service on Play Console?

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I've created an Android app that uses the Android Accessibility Service to detect and block inapropriate content on chrome, although the app itself isn't primarily focused on accessibility. I've uploaded it to the closed testing release track on the Google Play Console.

I'm wondering how much time it usually takes for the review process to complete in this situation. I know review times can vary, but I'm specifically interested in how using the Android Accessibility Service might affect the review duration.